# Detail plotting a function with Tikz in Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created 3 graphics with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[anchor=north] {$\alpha$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[anchor=north] {$\beta$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 2.05) edge (2.8, 2.05) node[anchor=north] {};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (2.8, 2.05) edge (2.8, 0.55) node[anchor=north] {};
    \shade[ball color = red] (0.5, 2.05) circle (2pt);
    \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 2.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[anchor=north] {$\alpha$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[anchor=north] {$\beta$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 0.55) edge (2.8, 0.55) node[anchor=north] {};
    \shade[ball color = red] (2.8, 0.55) circle (2pt);
    \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 0.55);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[anchor=north] {$\alpha$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[anchor=north] {$\beta$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (1.65, 0) edge (1.65, 1.05) node[anchor=north] {$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 1.05) edge (2.8, 1.05) node[anchor=north] {};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (2.8, 1.05) edge (2.8, 0.55) node[anchor=north] {};
    \shade[ball color = red] (1.65, 1.05) circle (2pt);
    \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 1.05);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
However, I would like to have the three graphics vertically aligned and I would like to add some text beneath them, like in this example:
[image]

How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but with  very few exceptions, you should load hyperref after the other packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can align the x-axis of your plots by specifying a baseline for the TikZ pictures. This way you don't have to worry if they have different sizes and their abscissa will automatically be aligned (which would not be the case if one would just bottom align them, as done by the usual packages for subfigures):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=center,yshift=-2ex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
    \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[mynode] {$\alpha$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[mynode] {$\beta$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 2.05) edge (2.8, 2.05);
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (2.8, 2.05) edge (2.8, 0.55);
    \shade[ball color = red] (0.5, 2.05) circle (2pt);
    \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 2.05);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
    \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[mynode] {$\alpha$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[mynode] {$\beta$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 0.55) edge (2.8, 0.55);
    \shade[ball color = red] (2.8, 0.55) circle (2pt);
    \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 0.55);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
    \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[mynode] {$\alpha$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[mynode] {$\beta$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (1.65, 0) edge (1.65, 1.05) node[mynode] {$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$};
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 1.05) edge (2.8, 1.05);
    \path[-, dashed, color = red] (2.8, 1.05) edge (2.8, 0.55);
    \shade[ball color = red] (1.65, 1.05) circle (2pt);
    \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 1.05);
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill\mbox{}%

\subcaptionbox{A cat}{\hspace{.33\linewidth}}%
\subcaptionbox{A cat}{\hspace{.33\linewidth}}%
\subcaptionbox{A cat}{\hspace{.33\linewidth}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks! How could I also align vertically alpha, (alpha + beta)/2 and beta? I think it looks nicer (as in the second image)

Comment: Thank you very much for the editing.

Comment: @JorgeRubio See my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Like how this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[anchor=north] {$\alpha$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[anchor=north] {$\beta$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 2.05) edge (2.8, 2.05) node[anchor=north] {};
        \path[-, dashed, color = red] (2.8, 2.05) edge (2.8, 0.55) node[anchor=north] {};
        \shade[ball color = red] (0.5, 2.05) circle (2pt);
        \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 2.05);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption for the first graphic.}
    \label{fig:sub1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[anchor=north] {$\alpha$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[anchor=north] {$\beta$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 0.55) edge (2.8, 0.55) node[anchor=north] {};
        \shade[ball color = red] (2.8, 0.55) circle (2pt);
        \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 0.55);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption for the second graphic.}
    \label{fig:sub2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-0.3, 0) -- (3.3, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \draw[->] (0, -0.3) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \draw[thick, domain=0.5:2.8, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (0.5, 0) edge (0.5, 2) node[anchor=north] {$\alpha$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (2.8, 0) edge (2.8, 0.5) node[anchor=north] {$\beta$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = Green4] (1.65, 0) edge (1.65, 1.05) node[anchor=north] {$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$};
        \path[-, dashed, color = red] (0.5, 1.05) edge (2.8, 1.05) node[anchor=north] {};
        \path[-, dashed, color = red] (2.8, 1.05) edge (2.8, 0.55) node[anchor=north] {};
        \shade[ball color = red] (1.65, 1.05) circle (2pt);
        \fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5, 0) rectangle (2.8, 1.05);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption for the third graphic.}
    \label{fig:sub3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main caption for the three graphics.}
  \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

Some text below the graphics.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can customize the width of each subfigure by changing the value of `0.3\textwidth`. The `\hfill` commands distribute the subfigures horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Redraw ordinates so that all images are equal height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small, 
            justification=raggedright]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nccmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\tikzset{
    tl/.style = {anchor=center, yshift=-2.4ex},
    ln/.style = {draw, color=#1, densely dashed},
  Ball/.style = {ball color = red},
        }
\newcommand\axis{
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (3.2, 0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}$};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.8) + (0,0.6) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$\mathbb{R}$};
                }
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ya}{sin(2*0.5 r) + 1.2}           % 2*0.5 +1.2
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yb}{sin(2*2.8 r) + 1.2}           % 2*2.8  + 1-2
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yc}{sin(2*(0.5+2.8)/2  r) + 1.2}  % 2*(0.5+2.8)/2 +1.2
%%%% images
\subfloat[Caption for the first graphic.    \label{subfig:a}]%
{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\axis
\draw[thick, blue, domain=0.5:2.8, samples=100] plot (\x, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});

\path[ln=Green4](0.5, 0) edge ++ (0,\ya) node[tl] {$\alpha$}
                (2.8, 0) edge ++ (0,\yb) node[tl] {$\beta$};
\path[ln=red]   (0.5, \ya)  -|  (2.8, \yb);
\shade[Ball]    (0.5, \ya) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5,0) rectangle (2.8, \ya);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Caption for the second graphic.    \label{subfig:b}]%
{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\axis
\draw[thick, blue, domain=0.5:2.8, samples=100] plot (\x, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});

\path[ln=Green4](0.5, 0) edge ++ (0,\ya) node[tl] {$\alpha$}
                (2.8, 0) edge ++ (0,\yb) node[tl] {$\beta$};
\path[ln=red]   (0.5, \yb)  --  (2.8, \yb);
\shade[Ball]    (2.8, \yb) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5,0) rectangle (2.8, \yb);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Caption for the second graphic.    \label{subfig:c}]%
{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\axis
\draw[thick, blue, domain=0.5:2.8, samples=100] plot (\x, {sin(2*\x r) + 1.2});

\path[ln=Green4](0.5, 0) edge ++ (0,\ya) node[tl] {$\alpha$}
                (2.8, 0) edge ++ (0,\yb) node[tl] {$\beta$}
                (1.65,0) edge ++ (0,\yc) node[tl] {$\mfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$};
\path[ln=red]   (0.5, \yc)  -|  (2.8, \yb);
\shade[Ball]    (1.65,\yc) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill[OrangeRed1, opacity = 0.15] (0.5,0) rectangle (2.8, \yc);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\caption{Main caption for the three graphics.}
\label{fig:main}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Comments:**
In comparison to your and other solution the4 above MWE has the follow3ing main differences:

- defined command for drawing coordinate systems(so that all images are equal height),
- common definition of image elements styles
- defied macros for calculations of y-coordinates used in images,
- used `\subfloat` environments as are emulated by `subcaption` package version 3.1 or newer.